# Execute os.system command without overwriting the output

Tags: python

I want to execute os.system command multiple times for several generated output from processes executed in the script without overwriting the output which is in database format .. I tired the following but still overwrites the output from the first run

```
for x in range(fileNumbers):        
os.system('"C:\\Soil\\soil.exe-PROFILE "C:\\SOIL\\dpsoilin' +str(x) + '.txt" - OUTPUT DATABASE"') 
shutil.copyfile('soilout.db3','Exported\\soilout'+str(x)+'.db3')
```

Comment: You say 'override', but I assume you mean 'overwrite'? The problem is most likely that `soil.exe-PROFILE` creates the output file in another location than the current working directory for the script. Are you seeing copies appear in the `Exported` folder, or does it stay empty?

Comment: You are correct .. overwrites .. actually I started with having no shutil.copyfile but the result was only one file after all the x runs .. then I thought shutil.copyfile will solve the issue but it copied one of the runs x amount of times ... I assume from the first run ... the command is repeated with different inputs generated in the script and named with the  str(x)  .. I appreciate any ideas here

Comment: It look like, if you fixed you indentation, it should give you one file per x. Have you tried debugging it and seeing exactly what this loop does? What is 'filecontents' when it executes?  Maybe try printing out the file name each time?

Comment: The command produces a database file named  soilout.dp3 .. I do not know if you can add something to this executable command to produce the output for each run with adding a sting x to it .l. but the way it is .. is that it produces a file with the same name each time and therefore it overwrites the files I believe

Comment: The code you provided is incorrectly indented - which makes me wonder if that's the case for your original code as well. Please update the code to accurately represent the way it looks in the original. Also, you say it produces `soilout.dp3` but you copy `soilout.db3` - people can be forgiving about spelling errors, but code never is. The arrangement of double quotes in the `os.system` parameter also seems very suspect - perhaps you can add a line of example code to your question that shows the command you expect to be run, without all the quotes, string construction and escape chars?

Comment: Sorry a spelling mistake in my comment .. in the code the file is producing database file .db3